# Как получить ссылку

Tags: java, android

Имеется короткая ссылка на Тик-Ток https://vm.tiktok.com/WeAnGo/ и если я перехожу по этой ссылке, то у меня получается вот такая ссылка 
https://m.tiktok.com/v/6815385649177185537.html?u_code=dbmd35ac9e68mk&preview_pb=0&language=ru&_d=dbmd394427127c&timestamp=1586869942&user_id=6815039764145701894&utm_source=copy&utm_campaign=client_share&utm_medium=android&share_app_name=musically&share_iid=6815040446029858566, как получить мне эту ссылку и занести её в String?

Comment: Через `HttpClient`

Comment: Сделать запрос по короткой ссылке и взять из ответа заголовок `Location`. Конкретный пример зависит какими средствами будете делать запрос. Для общего понимания почитайте что такое редирект.